# Function is not defined when calling from app

Tags: javascript, android, soap

I have been trying to figure this out for awhile now and I feel like it is going to be something pretty easy. Little summary of what is going on:

I am getting a .js file from my internal network to get functions. My function is defined in there but when I try to run it, the debugger says that it is not defined. I can run other functions from the same file so I think that it is a syntax error that I cannot find.  I attached the code below. Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance!

```
function getCurrentAds(){
var rs = new XMLHttpRequest();
rs.open("POST", "[WebService]", false);
rs.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","[WebService]");
rs.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
var packet = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetMajorInfo xmlns='[WebService]' /></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
rs.send(packet);
var result = rs.responseXML;
var r = "";

x=result.getElementsByTagName("MJR");
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    r += "Major Code: " + x[i].getAttribute("Mjr_cd") + "\n";
    r += "Description: " + x[i].getAttribute("DES") + "\n\n";
} 

rs.close;
alert(r);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA! Figured it out. Kind of stupid of me. I needed to clear the cache of the Application on the device that I was using. So for anyone that runs into this problem, clear the cache and it should all work. Now I need to figure out how to clear the cache on the app closing so the user doesn't need to clear the cache every time I update my web service. Any ideas?